# A weird property happens ,When I use super() to extend from another class

Tags: python

A weird property happens when I use `super()` to extend from another class. This is the code:

```py
from depot.io.local import LocalFileStorage

class ScriptLocalFileStorage2(LocalFileStorage):

    def create(self, fileid, *args, **kwargs):
        new_file_id = fileid
        content, filename, content_type = self.fileinfo(*args, **kwargs)
        super().__save_file(new_file_id, content, filename, content_type)
        return new_file_id
```

This is the error:

```py
In [1]: from depot.manager import DepotManager
   ...: DepotManager.configure('scripts2', {'depot.backend': 'app.utils.ScriptLocalFileStorage2', 'depot.storage_path': '/Users/jason/PycharmProjects/sw-edge/app/static/scri
   ...: pts'})
   ...: depot = DepotManager.get('scripts2')
   ...: fileid = depot.create("123fsfl1fdfd3232sfsdfdsff", open('/Users/yinhezhixing/Downloads/simple.txt','rb'))
<app.utils.ScriptLocalFileStorage2 object at 0x113d4aeb8>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-8438648c61e5> in <module>
      2 DepotManager.configure('scripts2', {'depot.backend': 'app.utils.ScriptLocalFileStorage2', 'depot.storage_path': '/Users/jason/PycharmProjects/sw-edge/app/static/scripts'})
      3 depot = DepotManager.get('scripts2')
----> 4 fileid = depot.create("123fsfl1fdfd3232sfsdfdsff", open('/Users/yinhezhixing/Downloads/simple.txt','rb'))

~/PycharmProjects/sw-edge/app/utils.py in create(self, fileid, *args, **kwargs)
    254         new_file_id = fileid
    255         content, filename, content_type = self.fileinfo(*args, **kwargs)
--> 256         super().__save_file(new_file_id, content, filename, content_type)
    257         return new_file_id

AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '_ScriptLocalFileStorage2__save_file'
```

I expected it to create a file with fileid "123fsfl1fdfd3232sfsdfdsff", but an unknown property `_ScriptLocalFileStorage2__save_file` happened.

Comment: Which Python version are you using?

Comment: That's called name mangling. Just try to prevent names starting with double underscore to avoid it.

Comment: I use Python 3.6.2.

Answer (score 2):

The double underscore method `__save_file()` is subject to 'Name Mangling' because it is a 'private' method see [docs here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables). Because of the name mangling you can see that the method you are actually calling is `_ScriptLocalFileStorage2__save_file`.

In general you really should avoid calling private methods - is there a public method you can use instead.

Comment: How can I override the method that has another private method self.__save_file().